# Install virtualenv on Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, python

I come from Ubuntu. I know how to install virtualenv and configure stuff on Ubuntu. Now Fedora seems pretty strange to me...

Following these two guides:

[Setting up virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper and IPython on Fedora](http://rawpackets.com/2011/10/02/setting-up-virtualenv-pip-virtualenvwrapper-and-ipython-on-fedora/)
[How to Install Virtualenv in Fedora 16 / 15 / 14](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/how-to-install-virtualenv-in-fedora-15-and-14/)

I am getting this when I tried to setup my virtualenv

> bash: virtualenv: command not found...

I installed under root. If I do `ls`:

```
$ su -
[root@localhost ~]# ls
anaconda-ks.cfg  bin  lib
[root@localhost bin]# ls
virtualenv  virtualenvwrapper.sh
[root@localhost bin]# 
[root@localhost bin]# cd
[root@localhost ~]# cd lib
[root@localhost lib]# ls
python2.7
[root@localhost lib]# cd python2.7/
[root@localhost python2.7]# ls
site-packages
[root@localhost python2.7]# cd site-packages/
[root@localhost site-packages]# ls
virtualenv-1.7-py2.7.egg-info  virtualenvwrapper
virtualenv.py                  virtualenvwrapper-2.11-py2.7.egg-info
virtualenv.pyc                 virtualenvwrapper-2.11-py2.7-nspkg.pth
virtualenv_support
[root@localhost site-packages]#
```

The `bin` and `lib` contains virtualenv. They appear after I installed virtualenv through pip. (I checked this against my fresh Fedora on my laptop, lib and bin do not exist under root directory). During the installation, it was clear to me that virtualenv was installed under the root directory.

How do I fix this? What is the correct way to install virtualenv on Fedora? (I know how to do this on Ubuntu...)

I think `su -` is bad. plain su will log me in as root but put me in my user's directory instead of the root directory (in the case of `su -`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
yum install python-virtualenv
```

​

Comment: Weird. I was pretty confident that I installed it. Thanks. I just rescue and did it again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Now for Fedora 25...

Python 2

```
sudo dnf install python-virtualenv
```

Python 3

```
sudo dnf install python3-virtualenv
```